# Setting charset encoding in Javascript application

Tags: javascript, web-services, soap, character-encoding

I am calling a SOAP service in my Javascript code, and the response of this service is correct but strings returned does not show letters with accents. So, I have a problem with encoding charset and I am trying the following actions:

1) I ensure that the HTTP response returning string data has the correct charset defined. So, I have checked with https://validator.w3.org/i18n-checker/ that the encoding charset of the URI that I am calling is "utf-8".

2) I have defined charset in the head section of html:

```
<meta charset='utf-8' content-type="text/xml;charset=UTF-8"/>
```

3) Also,  I call this service with a function in module.js, I have also defined

```
<script src="node_modules/my_module.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

All three with the same wrong result.
I added an image with the some examples:
[image with result strings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDk0U.png), where in green square have to say 'Sant Martí de Tous', in red 'Moianès', in blue 'Santa Bàrbara', 'Montsià', in orange 'Torroella de Montgrí', etc

This is a minimum sample code to call SOAP service with tinysoap library:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' content-type="text/xml; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>Test Charset Encoding</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.15/esri/themes/light/main.css"/>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/tinysoap/tinysoap-browser-min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.15/"></script>

    <script>
        var tinySoap=this.tinysoap;

        require(["esri/Map"], function(Map) { 
          var inputCtrl  = document.getElementById("inputString"); // gironès
          var outputCtrl = document.getElementById("outputString"); 

          inputCtrl.onchange = function() {
              var userTxtValue = inputCtrl.value;
              var args = {nom: userTxtValue};

              //console.log("[INPUT] : ",args);
              //outputCtrl.innerHTML = "<br><b>Input ... </b>" + userTxtValue +"<br>";

              tinySoap.createClient(url, function(err, client){
                  client.localitzaToponim(args, function(err, result) {
                      var data = result['item'];

                      //console.log("[OUTPUT] : ",data);
                      //outputCtrl.innerHTML += "<b>Output ... </b>";
                      //data.forEach(element => {
                      //    outputCtrl.innerHTML +=  "<br>      "+ element.Nom;
                      //});

                  });
              });
          }
          });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    Look for place or address ...
    <input id="inputString" size="50" value=""><br>
    <span id="outputString"></span>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is the [result of this process for 'gironès' as input string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wo4H7.png)
There is the error: "Refused to set unsafe header", but I can not see where to set header parameters to connection.

I am still working in that problem: I have checked that strings are encoded as UTF16 with this library: `https://github.com/polygonplanet/encoding.js/`
using `Encoding.detect(string)`, but `Encoding.convert(string,'utf8','utf16')` does not work for me, neither `Encoding.convert(string,'latin1','utf16')`, etc

What is the right way to define the encoding charset? Thank you

Comment: Please [edit] the question and share a garbled text along with its correct equivalent (non-trivial string with at least 2..3 garbled accented letters).

Comment: Thanks for your time @JosefZ, I have just added some examples.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set character encoding in SOAP request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33752787/how-to-set-character-encoding-in-soap-request). Otherwise, share a [mcve] please.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @JosefZ but I am working with tinySoap.js library (https://github.com/mhzed/tinysoap) to connect with SOAP service, so I haven't option to set enconding charset in HttpURLConnection. I am going to prepare some code lines to share. Thanks!